# How can I get list of plugin dependencies?

Tags: maven

[It is said](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2008/04/how-to-override-a-plugins-dependency-in-maven/) that:

> Maven 2.0.9 introduced the ability to override a dependency used by a
>   plugin.    This is handy when you want to use a newer checkstyle, pmd,
>   etc jar than is included by default in the plugin.

My question is - how can I get list of dependencies of some specific plugin just as easy as I can get list of dependencies of the project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Executing [`mvn dependency:resolve-plugins`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/resolve-plugins-mojo.html) will provide a list of all the plugins defined within your POM (and those inherited from any parent POMs) along with all the dependencies of each plugin.

Comment: can't believe I've missed that. Thank you.